# What is inside vesamenu.c32 of syslinux?

Tags: syslinux

What is inside `vesamenu.c32`?

I need NOT know the PURPOSE of this file, I wish to know what it is.

Are there machine instructions inside or what? If yes, then what are they doing?

Answer (score 1):

`file` says

```
/usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/vesamenu.c32: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

so it's a 32-bit binary for Intel CPUs. It's built from the files in [`com32/menu`](http://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/tree/HEAD:/com32/menu); the code allows a menu to be defined and displayed.

Comment: Does this code contain network (like TFTP) reading instructions or just functions to operate video buffer? Can I see it's entry points or something?

Comment: You're a C programmer, you should be able to figure it out easily enough ;-).

Comment: Yes, I can see something, thanks for providing link to source code, but I don't understand the final file structure. Can I just load it into memory and pass control to some starting point? Or I just get some functions which I can call? Is this the same as "kernel"?

Comment: You can't quite run it directly, but control starts at [`main() in mainmenu.c`](http://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/com32/menu/menumain.c#l1103) in the standard way for C programs. From SYSLINUX it is loaded like a kernel (from [`run_default.c`](http://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/com32/lib/syslinux/run_default.c)), and the process from there to `main()` is handled by the `crt0` code.

Comment: Why doesn't `file` command report "LSB shared object" for kernel image then? (it reports DBF file for me, probably by mistake)? Looks like kernel is raw code? Or loader can determine the type of imge dynamically?

Comment: Nowadays the kernel is an EFI-compatible PE binary which also happens to start with a valid boot sector. The SYSLINUX loader handles various types of images; you should really try to read the code yourself (starting from `run_default.c` if you're interested in the loader), it's quite straightforward. What are you actually trying to figure out?

Comment: I would like to fill my knowledge gap to be able to compose various boot menus etc